# React-Native-Firebase - cloudDocumentTextRecognizerProcessImage is not a function

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to implement Text Recognition into my project.
When I'm calling: `ml().cloudDocumentTextRecognizerProcessImage(media.uri);`
It shows this error:
[image: error]

My Code:

```
const onImageSelect = async (media) => {
        if (!media.didCancel) {
            // Text Recognition Process
            setImage(media.uri);
            const processingResult = await ml().cloudDocumentTextRecognizerProcessImage(media.uri);
            console.log(processingResult);
            setResult(processingResult);
            setLicenseNumber(processingResult);
        }
    };
```